# Повторная регистрация

Tags: php, javascript, регистрация

К примеру, у меня есть платный доступ к странице. Первый месяц доступ бесплатный. Но проблема в том, что пользователь по истечению месяца может зарегистрироваться заново, создать новый аккаунт, пройдя регистрацию под другим именем, с другим e-mail.

Как организовать запрет на повторную регистрацию, чтобы пользователь не мог создать новый аккаунт и пользоваться месяц бесплатным доступом?

Comment: Добавьте еще телефон или замените e-mail на телефон. Новую симку простые люди реже добывают, чем почту.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, я думал об этом. Но тогда нужно, сделать подтверждение телефона, иначе, будут писать любые телефоны. А сделать такой сервис авто оправки смс , для меня трудновато.

Comment: Не знаю, насколько это возможно, но может быть можно сделать не СМС-рассылку, а использовать telegram-бота, скорее всего это выйдет дешевле, чем использовать СМС-шлюзы.

Comment: Нравится идея с телеграмм ботом. Если загоритесь желанием, сделаю рабочий пример, но на nodeJS. А вообще ставьте куку на 5 лет, большинство не знает как ее удалять.

Comment: @TotalPusher Ну, за 5 лет человек винду переустановить может несколько раз, не говоря о чистке куков. И мне кажется, что те, кто используют регистрацию с кучи разных e-mail, чтобы бесплатно пользоваться, скорее всего уже в курсе того, как чистить куки.

Comment: Сделайте авторизацию через OAuth вконтакте и одноклассники. Если не ошибаюсь, они возвращают email или ID. Способ с недостатками, но рассмотрите такой вариант.

Comment: Был такой вопрос и советовал я это: при регистрации просите фотографию человека на фоне монитора с открытым вашим сайтом и развернутым читаемым паспортом. В ручном режиме верифицируете фото. Все остальное не поможет.

Comment: по поводу телеграма - если выбере это, то сразу скажу что там надо будет привязываться именно к номеру телефона (его кнопкой можно боту отправлять), потому что username меняется в любой момент и может использоваться только для идентификации, а не такого контроля аккаунтов.

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно запрашивать данные банковской карточки, ну, и паспортные данные.

Сервис автоотправки СМС необязательно делать самому, есть готовые сервисы, только платные.

Comment: Доброе утро. А на каком основании запрашивать данные банковской карты или паспортные данные? У Вас есть на это право? Не, конечно можно, если Вы хотите распугать посетителей сайта.

Comment: Подобным образом можно сфальсифицировать и паспортные\банковские данные. Проверить их правдивость невозможно.

Comment: Паспортные данные проверяются как минимум на действительность такого номера и серии паспорта, а с банковской карты можно списывать символическую сумму.

Comment: Не каждый пользователь,решиться оставить свой номер мобильного-боясь что снимут деньги, а про паспорт я вообще молчу

Comment: Значит, продукт им не нужен даже бесплатно.

Comment: Я не просил критиковать мой продукт, я просил дать совет, как избежать эту проблему.

Comment: Никто вам не даст ничего нового без конкретики.

Comment: более того, есть законы о персональных данных, т.е. обязателен ssl, определённые технические характеристики и всё такое.

Comment: @Maximmka ну, SSL мой заказчик просил ввести и без этого, а из-за SEO (по его словам\мнению), а тех. хар., которых не видно, то не докажут.